# How To Update MAX() Value - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables:

tableA

```
id  name    group_id    group_name  sub_state
1   User1       1            MG      active
2   User3       3            AG      active
```

TableB

```
tableA_id       v_date                group_id
   1        2020-01-20T21:51:24.000Z     1          
   2        2020-03-10T21:20:24.000Z     3   
   1        2020-05-05T23:20:24.000Z     1   
   2        2020-05-13T23:20:24.000Z     3
```

I want to update the most recent `v_date` of each user for a new date. I believe using MAX() would be useful here.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE tableB
SET v_date = '2020-05-27 20:00:13+00'
WHERE v_date = (SELECT MAX(v_date) FROM tableB
     LEFT JOIN tableA ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id AND tableB.group_id = tableA.group_id
     WHERE tableA.sub_state = 'active'
     GROUP BY tableA.id);
```

This query returns the error: `Query Error: error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Then I tried:

```
WITH stat AS (
    SELECT MAX(v_date) FROM tableB
    LEFT JOIN tableA ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id AND tableB.group_id = tableA.group_id
    WHERE tableA.sub_state = 'active' AND tableA.group_id = 1
    GROUP BY tableA.id
)   
UPDATE tableB
SET v_date = '2020-05-27 20:00:13+00'
FROM stat
WHERE group_id = 1;
```

This changes the date of all the records, not just the last one or recent one.

How can I update the last record from each user without affecting all the records from all the time?

Comment: you are selecting MAX(v_date) from TableA. but v_date is not present in your sample data. Please update the correct details

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I don't think that thats the issue, because the other table is being joined (don't know if it was because it was confusing). I still updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
UPDATE tableB
SET v_date = '2020-05-27 20:00:13+00'
WHERE v_date = (
    SELECT MAX(tb1.v_date) 
    FROM tableB tb1
    WHERE tb1.tableA_id = tableB.tableA_id
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @GMB! This did exactly what I wanted!